# Kotlin coroutines ClosedSendChannelException

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I send data by channel in the method in ViewModel and close it after coroutine completed:

```
private fun requestNextPageFromRemote() {
    viewModelScope.launch(handler) {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            coroutineContext[Job]?.invokeOnCompletion {
                channel.close()
            }
            channel.send(true)
            interactor.requestPageOfFilmsFromRemoteDataSource(NEXT_PAGE)
            getNextPageFromDataSource()
            channel.send(false)
        }
    }
}
```

When enter this method second time, I receive ClosedSendChannelException.
Is there need to reopen the channel every time and how to do it?

Comment: I don't think you can re-open a channel. How would the consumer coroutine know that it's open again? It seems you could just not close it in the first place. It also seems odd you have a round-about way of closing it in a completion listener instead of just putting that as the last line of code in this coroutine. And you're nesting a coroutine in another coroutine that does nothing besides launching the nested one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. The consumer coroutine is opened from different scope and from another place. I'm nesting coroutines because I need put handler in parent cor. The question is if I take page from server lets say 1 in minute? I should to close the channel. How I open it next time?

Comment: maybe `SharedFlow` is what you need instead of `Channel`. Consider it. It doesn't require to be closed, and it is a hot stream.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let's assume generally you need the channel. And you need it not always, bit sometimes.  The question is - how you can use it after it has been closed? Or after it has been closed it becomes unusable at all?

Comment: Closing it destroys it forever. Why do you need to close it? It would help to see your code on the consumer side. What is `handler`? I think you might misunderstand how to use and combine CoroutineContexts, and also when you actually need to specify dispatchers. Is `requestPageOfFilmsFromRemoteDataSource` or `getNextPageFromDataSource` a blocking function? If they are not blocking, you don't need to specify a Dispatcher. Even if they are, you can combine `handler` and a specific dispatcher using `handler + Dispatchers.IO` in the top level coroutine.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to understand this much better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who helped me to understand the issue. I changed my code this way:

```
private val exceptionHandler =
    CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e -> errorEvent.postValue(App.instance.getString(R.string.exc_handler_msg) + e) }
private val homeFragmentViewModelContext =
    viewModelScope.coroutineContext.plus(exceptionHandler + Dispatchers.IO)
private val homeFragmentViewModelScope = CoroutineScope(homeFragmentViewModelContext)
```

and the method:

```
    private fun requestNextPageFromRemote() {
        homeFragmentViewModelScope.launch {
            channel.send(true)
            interactor.requestPageOfFilmsFromRemoteDataSource(NEXT_PAGE)
            getNextPageFromDataSource()
            channel.send(false)
        }
    }
```

And there is no need to close the channel.

The consumer method:

```
    private fun exposeProgressBar() = viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        for (element in homeFragmentViewModel.channel) {
            fragmentHomeBinding.progressBar.isVisible = element
        }
    }
```